# How to execute the same setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with my setInterval(), my code is:

```
    var1=0;
function addNum(){
    var1++;
    $('.number').text(var1);
}



$(function() {
    $('.number').text(var1);

    jQuery('#box').on('touchstart touchmove', function(e) {

        mytimer = setInterval(function(){ addNum() }, 500);

    });
    jQuery('#box').on('touchend touchcancel', function(e) {
        alert('lift up');
        window.clearInterval(100);    

      });
    });
```

I can't clearInterval()
How can I use the same setInterval for the next time?

Somebody knows, how to reuse it?

BR,
Christian

Comment: Unrelated. You shouldn't use `clearTimeout(100);` but `clearTimeout(mytimer);`

Comment: Can you explain what you try to acheive?

Comment: have a look at this example to get an understanding on how it works -- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval

Comment: There must be 100 dups of this question.

Comment: sorry guys! I'm trying to add 1 to my var each second while my user touch the screen! When the user lift up the finger, the timer must be stopped.  my example is:  https://jsfiddle.net/eLv0cx1n/

Comment: @ jfriend00 -- yea well, this is were AI comes in handy to scan the question before submit and show the OP the duplicates

Comment: The problem is how to lauch the timer with a button and how to stop it, the we need to relaunch a new timer! Thanks @Tasos

Comment: define a global variable (thats outside the function) and stick -- myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000); -- in the click function to start it -- to stop it i gave you a link to an example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aeakeqnv/

Comment: Log on _touchmove_ and you'll see it will fire a lot more often than _touchcancel_ - similar to how the _mousemove_ event fires a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your clear function to `window.clearInterval(mytimer);`